# Async.eachSeries executing in parallel

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js

I'm trying to understand `async` library from node.js and apply it, but it doesn't work as expected. Called are made in parallels when I was expecting them to be made in series (i.e. one after another)

Here is my code

```
        var users = [{_id:'1',username:'user1'},{_id:'2',username:'user2'}];            
        async.eachSeries(users,function function1(user,callbackEach){

            var username = user.username;
            var incomes = [{source:'sourceA',provider:providerA},{source:'sourceB',provider:providerB},{source:'sourceC',provider:providerC}];

            async.eachSeries(incomes,function function2(income,callbackSmallEach){
                var source = income.source;

                income.provider.getEarnings(user._id,username,yesterday,function callbackFromGetEarnings(err,result){
                    if (err){
                        // error
                    } else {

                        income.earnings = {day : new Number(result)};

                        income.provider.getMonthEarnings(user._id,username,yesterday,function callbackFromGetMonthEarnings(err,monthTotal){
                            if (err){
                                // error
                            } else {
                                income.earnings.month = new Number(monthTotal);
                                callbackSmallEach();
                            }
                        }); 

                    }   
                });
            },              
            function sendEmails(err){
                if (err) {
                    // error
                } else {
                    // send email 
                }
            });

            console.log("Just before calling callbackEach()");
            callbackEach();
        });
```

`getEarnings` and `getMonthEarnings` use an external provider, so some time can occur until callback functions `callbackFromGetEarnings` and `callbackFromGetMonthEarnings` are called.

My problem is that I dont want both calls to `getEarnings` to be executed in parallel. I want function `getEarnings` for `user2` to be called only after `getEarnings` for `user1` has returned (and corresponding callbacks have been made).

As you can see I have tried to make the calls for user1 and 2 in a serie, with `async.eachSeries` but calls are made in parallel. When I execute, the log `Just before calling callbackEach()` is always executed before the callback function `callbackFromGetEarnings` is called...

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: callbackEach(); should be inside the finish function of the inner async.eachSeries. In your code that would be inside the sendEmails function

Answer (score 1):

The problem is where you are calling your callback. Example:

```
async.eachSeries(something, function(item, callback) {
  async.eachSeries(item.somethingElse, function(subitem, callback2) {
    //do something
    return callback2();
  }, function() {
    //when all item.somethingElse is done, call the upper callback
    return callback();
  })
}, function() {
  console.log('done');
})
```

This way, for each item in something, you will execute in series all the item.somethingElse, before going to the next item.